# Xamarin Forms: Webview showing slight black line at bottom

Tags: ios, webview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am creating an app using Xamarin Forms using PCL project. In ios, a black line is shown at the bottom of the web view only. I don't experience the same issue in android or windows 10.

Comment: check your  html code in link which you have passed to webview. And check that link in browser also .

Comment: @KKRocks in webpage there is no black line at bottom.

Comment: I've had that same thing in a app of mine. I think I fixed it with a custom renderer, let me find it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, I dealt with this before. It has to do with the background color of the webview. I have tried several things, the only thing that worked was setting this:

```
webView.Opaque = false;
webView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
```

In a custom renderer on the `UIWebView`.

A complete implemented custom renderer would then look like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (WebView), typeof (WebViewRenderer))]

namespace YourApp.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class WebViewRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (NativeView != null) {
                var webView = (UIWebView)NativeView;

                webView.Opaque = false;
                webView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share a sample custom renderer for webview.